# JS files problem (its methods still working even if I physically delete them (js files))

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have weird problem. I'm using Eclipse for writing J2EE (java, jsf, javascript) application and a standard JS files for javaScript/jQuery code. And it works.

But after some time, the changes which I make in JS file are not forwarded to application and I have to delete it (js file) and make new one with else name.

Even when I keep `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/global.js"></script>` in xhtml file and global.js is already deleted, all methods are still working!!!

Do you ever met this kind of problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a caching problem.
if you are using Firefox and the javascript code remains the same, try:
Ctrl + Shift + R.

This reloads the page and overrides the cache.